# Android xml parser returning "Incorrect function"

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am parsing xml file from server using xmlParser in Android.

When i print content of xml in logcat by

Log.e("check it out baby", xml);

Then following is output:

```
06-12 21:02:23.019: E/check it out baby(14600):   <html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Incorrect function.
06-12 21:02:23.019: E/check it out baby(14600): </body></html>
06-12 21:02:23.019: E/manjin(14600): <html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Incorrect     function.
06-12 21:02:23.019: E/manjin(14600): </body></html>
06-12 21:02:35.963: W/KeyCharacterMap(14600): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
06-12 21:02:35.963: W/KeyCharacterMap(14600): Error loading keycharmap   file '/system/usr/keychars/bravo-keypad.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='bravo-keypad'
06-12 21:02:35.963: W/KeyCharacterMap(14600): Using default   keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-12 21:04:52.559: D/dalvikvm(14600): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2858 objects / 177688 bytes in 71ms
```

Please suggest

Comment: This needs more information. We can't tell what's happening in your code just based on xml that you are parsing. Post some of the relevant code from your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [@joshas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326393/506879) on this topic, and take a look at [the link shared by him](http://alldroid.org/archived/threads/14925.html).